# For same ticket, merging only latest correct changeset versus full history?

Tags: tfs, merge

Let's say I write some code for a ticket, and check it in for code review (changeset A). The review comes back illustrating some changes that need to be made. I make the required changes, and check it in (creating changeset B). Assuming changeset B renders changeset A obsolete, when it comes time to merge (perhaps from trunk to a deployment branch), should both changesets be merged into it, so that the history is kept, or only the final, correct changeset?

I was under the impression that a correct merge would contain all changes made to a file so that the history could be kept, and there are no dangling changesets in trunk. However, I'm getting some resistance on this in my team. Thoughts?

Comment: What's their argument against keeping full change history? it depends on your philosophy for what source control is. if it is meant to represent (a) some ideal version of your code where no one has ever made a mistake or (b) just the most current understanding.

Comment: For the most part, it seems like they just don't like the hassle of merging more than one changeset to subsequent branches. It isn't as tidy. But I have a hard time sacrificing accuracy for something like tidiness.

Comment: If that's the problem, I would consider switching to tfs git. Merging multiple commits is not a problem there.

Answer (score 0):

You should mostly be merging "latest" rather than picking and choosing changesets. If you merge latest then TFVC handles all of the details of merging multiple changesets. You can also choose to merge only up to a specific changeset rather than latest.

http://nakedalm.com/avoid-pick-n-mix-branching-anti-pattern/

As your delevlopers are choosing changesets to merge they are actively reducing the quality of the final product. You are in essence maximising the number of potential integration issues...